# Getting error while build Angular google maps AGM

Tags: angular

My angular application is failing to create a prod build. I have used AGM(angular google maps). I had followed every step:

> Installing "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0"
>
> import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
>
> AgmCoreModule.forRoot({ apiKey: '*********************', libraries: ["places"] }),
>
> ERROR in Directive ɵb in E:/omni-channel-web/omni-web/node_modules/@agm/core/agm-core.d.ts has no selector, please add it! Cannot determine the module for class ɵb in E:/omni-channel-web/omni-web/node_modules/@agm/core/agm-core.d.ts! Add ɵb to the NgModule to fix it.

Can someone please help me, I am breaking my head for 2 days

Comment: Did you 'npm install @agm/core'?

Comment: Angular 8?, I hve the same problem

Comment: `npm install @agm/core@1`

With this worked for me 

`ng build -- --prod`

Hope if its usefull

Comment: Version 1.0 does not have the option to enlarge the map. How to solve this?

Answer (score 9):

For Angular 8 use this:

```
npm install @agm/core@1
```

Answer (score 1):

For anglar 8+

```
npm install @agm/core@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you must add @types/googlemaps to your dependencies[enter link description here](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1872)